# Extending class attribute in Python

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time summarizing my question so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I have a class like such:

```
class MyClass:
    timer = 60
```

I want `timer` to represent an integer but also extend some custom methods. For example:

```
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> c.timer
60
>>> c.timer.wait() # This would wait 60 seconds
True
>>> c.timer
0
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: a and b are class variables, not instance. I dont think it is your intention, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but your MyClass can be implemented as follows:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0

    def do_some_operation(self):
        # do something using a and b
        # and return True if success
        self.a += 100;
        return True


c = MyClass()
print(c.do_some_operation()) # True
print(c.a)                   # 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to make a class that simulates the integers:

```
class Integer:
    value = 0
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Integer(self.value + other.value)
    #Would need to do the other basic arithmetic things. I'll leave that to you...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def do_some_operation(self):
        return True



class MyClass:
    a = Integer(0)
    b = Integer(0)


c = MyClass()

print c.a
print c.b

print c.a + c.b

print c.a.do_some_operation()
```

Gives:

```
0
0
0
True
```

I would be careful about doing this though. There may be another more suitable way.

Comment: How would I accomplish: `c.a == 60`?

Comment: You would have to implement the details of `do_some_operation` (and change it `wait`)